# How to make sure that a unique record is returned to each concurrent request from a asp.net controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, locking, action, unique

In one of our ASP.Net application we have to assign customer complaints to support executives. Customer complaints are storied in a database table. We use entity framework code first approach.

When the support executive logged in to the system he will be provided with the customer complaint (view) with one of the complaint assigned to him. Once he completes the formalities for the complaint and submit the information, he will get the next complaint assigned to him and he will continue the same till end of the day.

The challenge here is there are N number of support executives working concurrently and the same action method (AssignCustomerComplaint) is triggered at the same time. Now how will we make sure that each customer executive will get unique complaint that are not assigned.

Note : I already have a field in the database table to say whether the complaint is assigned to a support executive or not (storing the userid of the support executive). So in the business logic I am checking whether the complaint is assigned and if not then I am updating the userid field with the current user and then returning the view with the model. But in some scenario because of the concurrent requests, same complaint is returned to different support executives (the latest request again updates the userid field). It’s obvious that there is no lock applied to that record.

I can lock the controller action method till we assign a particular complaint to a support executive but wanted to check is there any better way of doing this without affecting the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle the assignment out of sync, since that's the only part that will have concurrency issues. If two complaints are logged at the same time and you simply retrieve the next rep to assign, there's the potential that both will be assigned to the same rep, instead of two different reps.

However, if you simply save the complaint and then schedule a background process to go back and assign unassigned complaints to reps in order, then you effectively remove the concurrency issues from the equation.

Comment: Hi Chris,  Your suggestion around background process will work but we don't have a background process at the movement to assign the complaints to support executives. What we have now is the action method which takes care of assigning the complaints to the support executives. As this requests are concurrent by the time we assign the userid to the field and update, an another thread is also assigns and updates the same record. That's the reason for duplicate complaints viewed by two executives.

Comment: That's my point. I'm suggest you stop having your action method assign and create a console app or something that can handle the assignment operation for complaints in bulk, instead of one at a time. If you don't want to go the console app approach, you can create another action endpoint for this purpose and use something like Revalee (http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/) to schedule this endpoint to be hit at a certain frequency you desire. The key with either approach, though is to bulk assign complaints out of sync with their individual creation.